Does including ‘today’ in the Datediff function mess up the automated calculation?
Background: I use RedCap to track expiration dates for temporary appointments in my department. The specific issue I am having is with a calculated field I use to track how many days are remaining until ann appointment expires.
The calculated field equation is:
datediff(‘today’,[appt_end_date],’d’,true)
Problem: I have to use the “fix calcs now” function within the data quality application on a daily basis to update the calculation. For every day that I forget to do that, the calculation is off by 1 days. For instance, the below picture reflects what I see after forgetting to check REDcap for 3 days.
Question: is this a system issue or a user issue?
Display of calculated field error
I am unsure what to try. I have searched for similar issues and can’t find much.

I want to say what you're seeing is known behavior. Specifically, calculated fields don't update until they are "viewed" within the record's interface. The "Fix calcs now" button is a shortcut to update those in bulk without having to open every single record.

One workaround is to create a report and use advanced filter logic with something like this:
datediff('today',[appt_end_date],'d',true) >= 0 and 
datediff('today',[appt_end_date],'d',true) < 10

This would return records in which the end date occurs between today and 10 days in the future.
